# Hide divs based on the result of a Javascript search

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a relatively simple Javascript search bar that works in 3 different modes:

1. Search text
2. Search distance to a pair of coordinates
3. Search distance to another pair of coordinates if the search term begins with `g`

The text and coordinates are stored in a JSON file that is fetched. The results of the search are displayed in a `card` element with three `body` divs. What I need is to hide two of those divs, depending on the search method used.

I've tried many of the answers given here but I keep getting errors like `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')"`.

Any help is much appreciated.

```js
const userCardTemplate = document.querySelector("[data-user-template]")
const userCardContainer = document.querySelector("[data-user-cards-container]")
const searchInput = document.querySelector("[data-search]")

// DEFINE HERE THE ELEMENTS I WANT TO HIDE <---
var itemDivs1 = document.getElementById("aaa")
var itemDivs2 = document.getElementById("bbb")
var itemDivs3 = document.getElementById("ccc")

let users = []
let results = []

searchInput.addEventListener("input", e => {
  results = []; //quickly empty array
  userCardContainer.innerHTML = "";

  const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
  const xy = value.split(' ')

  // wait for 4 chars
  if (parseFloat(value.length) >= 4) {
  users.forEach(user => {

  var distance
  // Search method based on distance, using 'g'
  if (xy[0] == "g") {
    var distance = Math.sqrt(
      Math.pow(parseFloat(xy[1]) - parseFloat(user.x1), 2) +
      Math.pow(parseFloat(xy[2]) - parseFloat(user.y1), 2))
      // If this condition is met, HIDE body_1 and body_3
      itemDivs1.style.display = 'none'
      itemDivs3.style.display = 'none'
  // Search method based on distance, NOT using 'g'
  } else{
    var distance = Math.sqrt(
      Math.pow(parseFloat(xy[0]) - parseFloat(user.x2), 2) +
      Math.pow(parseFloat(xy[1]) - parseFloat(user.y2), 2))
      // If this condition is met, HIDE body_1 and body_2
      itemDivs1.style.display = 'none'
      itemDivs2.style.display = 'none'
  }
  let fvalue = value.replace("1", "9")

  // Search method based on text
  if (user.mnames.includes(fvalue)) {
    // If this condition is met, HIDE body_2 and body_3
    itemDivs2.style.display = 'none'
    itemDivs3.style.display = 'none'
  }

  // Condition to show card
  const isVisible = user.mnames.includes(fvalue) || distance <= 5
  
  if (isVisible) {
    user.distance = distance
    results.push(
      user
    );
  }
})
  }
  
  // Sort and limit results
  results.sort((a, b) => a.distance - b.distance)
  results = results.slice(0, 10)
  results.forEach((u) => {
userCardContainer.append(u.element);
  });
})


fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ucc23/ucc/main/_clusters/generated.json")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
users = data.map(user => {
  const card = userCardTemplate.content.cloneNode(true).children[0]
  const header = card.querySelector("[data-header]")
  const body_1 = card.querySelector("[data-body_1]")
  const body_2 = card.querySelector("[data-body_2]")
  const body_3 = card.querySelector("[data-body_3]")
  card.querySelector("a").setAttribute("href", "https://url/" + user.name)

  header.textContent = user.name
  body_1.textContent = user.mnames.split(',')
  body_2.textContent = user.x1 + ',' + user.y1
  body_3.textContent = user.x2 + ',' + user.y2

  return {
    mnames: user.mnames,
    x1: user.x1,
    y1: user.y1,
    x2: user.x2,
    y2: user.y2,
    element: card
  }
})
  })
```

```css
.user-cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  gap: .25rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.card {
  border: 0px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.card > .header {
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
}

.card > .body_1 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card > .body_2 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card > .body_3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-container">
  <input type="search" id="search" data-search>
</div>
<div class="user-cards" data-user-cards-container></div>
<template data-user-template>
  <div class="card">
  <a href=""><div class="header" data-header></div></a>
  <div class="body_1" data-body_1 id="aaa"></div>
  <div class="body_2" data-body_2 id="bbb"></div>
  <div class="body_3" data-body_3 id="ccc"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error happens when you try to access `itemDivs1.style` because `itemDivs1` is `null`, therefore it can't find any properties on it

[image]

So why is it `null`? Well it looks like when you use the `<template>` tag it creates a new document! This seems to be the intended behavior [according to the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) - Please be sure to look at the support table at the bottom since it appear Firefox does not support this!

[image]

Because of this you can't just do `document.getElementById(...)` since it would be looking in the wrong document.  We need to look inside this new document.  You are already selecting the template tag and saving it to a `userCardTemplate` variable, so from there we can just call `userCardTemplate.content.querySelector("#aaa")` to find the elements we need inside the sub-document.

```js
const userCardTemplate = document.querySelector("[data-user-template]")
const userCardContainer = document.querySelector("[data-user-cards-container]")
const searchInput = document.querySelector("[data-search]")

// DEFINE HERE THE ELEMENTS I WANT TO HIDE <---
var itemDivs1 = userCardTemplate.content.querySelector("#aaa");
var itemDivs2 = userCardTemplate.content.querySelector("#bbb");
var itemDivs3 = userCardTemplate.content.querySelector("#ccc");

let users = []
let results = []

searchInput.addEventListener("input", e => {
  results = []; //quickly empty array
  userCardContainer.innerHTML = "";

  const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
  const xy = value.split(' ')

  // wait for 4 chars
  if (parseFloat(value.length) >= 4) {
    users.forEach(user => {

      var distance
      // Search method based on distance, using 'g'
      if (xy[0] == "g") {
        var distance = Math.sqrt(
          Math.pow(parseFloat(xy[1]) - parseFloat(user.x1), 2) +
          Math.pow(parseFloat(xy[2]) - parseFloat(user.y1), 2))
          // If this condition is met, HIDE body_1 and body_3
          itemDivs1.style.display = 'none'
          itemDivs3.style.display = 'none'
      // Search method based on distance, NOT using 'g'
      } else{
        var distance = Math.sqrt(
          Math.pow(parseFloat(xy[0]) - parseFloat(user.x2), 2) +
          Math.pow(parseFloat(xy[1]) - parseFloat(user.y2), 2))
          // If this condition is met, HIDE body_1 and body_2
          itemDivs1.style.display = 'none'
          itemDivs2.style.display = 'none'
      }
      let fvalue = value.replace("1", "9")

      // Search method based on text
      if (user.mnames.includes(fvalue)) {
        // If this condition is met, HIDE body_2 and body_3
        itemDivs2.style.display = 'none'
        itemDivs3.style.display = 'none'
      }

      // Condition to show card
      const isVisible = user.mnames.includes(fvalue) || distance <= 5

      if (isVisible) {
        user.distance = distance
        results.push(
          user
        );
      }
    });
  }
  
  // Sort and limit results
  results.sort((a, b) => a.distance - b.distance)
  results = results.slice(0, 10)
  results.forEach((u) => {
userCardContainer.append(u.element);
  });
})


fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ucc23/ucc/main/_clusters/generated.json")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    users = data.map(user => {
      const card = userCardTemplate.content.cloneNode(true).children[0]
      const header = card.querySelector("[data-header]")
      const body_1 = card.querySelector("[data-body_1]")
      const body_2 = card.querySelector("[data-body_2]")
      const body_3 = card.querySelector("[data-body_3]")
      card.querySelector("a").setAttribute("href", "https://url/" + user.name)

      header.textContent = user.name
      body_1.textContent = user.mnames.split(',')
      body_2.textContent = user.x1 + ',' + user.y1
      body_3.textContent = user.x2 + ',' + user.y2

      return {
        mnames: user.mnames,
        x1: user.x1,
        y1: user.y1,
        x2: user.x2,
        y2: user.y2,
        element: card
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.user-cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  gap: .25rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.card {
  border: 0px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.card > .header {
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
}

.card > .body_1 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card > .body_2 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card > .body_3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-container">
  <input type="search" id="search" data-search>
</div>
<div class="user-cards" data-user-cards-container></div>
<template data-user-template>
  <div class="card">
  <a href=""><div class="header" data-header></div></a>
  <div class="body_1" data-body_1 id="aaa"></div>
  <div class="body_2" data-body_2 id="bbb"></div>
  <div class="body_3" data-body_3 id="ccc"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you Chris, it does not seem to work though. The JSON is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ucc23/ucc/main/_clusters/generated.json) (it is fetched by the Javascript block)

Comment: Alos, since this is just part of the site, I'm not sure that removing the `<template>` will not have unexpected consequences...

Comment: Ok, take a look at my revised answer. Now it keeps the `<template>` and looks inside the sub-document for the elements.  The search seems to work too.

Comment: Thank you Chris, the search works now but the `div` elements are not being hidden. It always shows all three

Comment: That seems like a separate issue since this question was about resolving the error you were getting. Now it sounds like the code is error free but you have a logic issue to look into a debug. I am not familiar with what this code does or the specifics of how it should work, so you might need to post another question that explains what is not working and ask for help there.

Comment: The question is about hiding the `div` elements really, the error is just an issue that appears. And revising your answer I see that the error is still there, your code uses `#aaa`, `#bbb` and `#ccc` for the ids when the actual ids do not have `#`s

Comment: I switched the code the use `querySelector` instead of `getElementById`. `#aaa` is a query selector for an ID which will match `id="aaa"`. that absolutely works.  Query selectors use the same syntax as CSS, and in fact your code uses them on the first 3 lines to select element by HTML attributes.

Comment: "#aaa is a query selector for an ID which will match id="aaa"", I did not know that (I Know very little HTML/JS/CSS". Thank you!